# Inject a function before other function's body in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm trying to solve a functional equation for an unknown function `B` defined extensionally as such:

```
B f (λg.M) = (λg.f M)
```

that is, I'm looking for a function `B` (a shorthand for "inject before body") that, when called with a given function `f` and a lambda expression `(λg.M)` (where `M` is some expression in that lambda function's body), will prepend the function `f` before the expression `M`, treating that expression as a parameter the function `f` is applied to.

However, I encountered a problem: how to "strip" the binding `λg.` from the lambda expression `(λg.M)` to get just `M`? Is there any way to extract it? Is it possible at all?

And a related question, more general:
Are there any techniques for solving such functional equations to obtain a formula for the unknown function behaving according to a definition by some functional equation? (like the one above)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a general method for solving such problems, but in this particular case, you can take

```
B = λf.λh.(λg'. f (h g'))
```

With such B, we have

```
   B f (λg.M)
-> (λh.(λg'. f (h g'))) (λg.M)
-> (λg'. f ((λg.M) g'))
-> (λg'. f (M[g := g'] ))
```

Which is what you want, up to α equivalence.